# How do i change an existing text mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text

I can't figure out how to change an existing text mesh already in my scene. I have tried to use

```
void changeScore()
{
    TextMesh textObject = GameObject.Find ("scoreText").GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
    textObject.text = "test";
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have been trying multiple different methods to no avail.

Comment: That's how to change existing text mesh. What's wrong? What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work" ? Are you calling the `changeScore` function?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is correct, which means you're either

- not calling changeScore()
- getting an error message
- changing the TextMesh's text later in the frame before it is rendered